# How come Mahoraga didn't adapt to Sukuna's pyrokinetic ability?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

In this [article](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Sukuna_vs._Mahoraga#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20finish%20the,that%20completely%20annihilates%20the%20shikigami.), you can see how the fight went between Sukuna and Mahoraga. The climax of the fight goes like this:

> Mahoraga is severely injured by this but survives the ordeal. Sukuna knows the only way to beat Mahoraga is to slaughter it with a different technique before it can adapt. He believes the shikigami has not only adapted to dismantle, but to slashing techniques in general. In order to finish the fight, Sukuna decides to unleash the pyrokinetic ability he used to defeat Jogo. He fires an immensely powerful fire arrow at Mahoraga before it can regenerate, creating a giant explosive pillar of fire from the impact that completely annihilates the shikigami.

How come Mahoraga was able to adapt to using **Cleave and Dismantle** through Sukuna's ***Domain Expansion: Malevolent Shrine*** sending an endless barrage of slashing attacks but couldn't adapt to the **Pyrokinetic ability** (used against Jogo) which incinerates Shikigami with a giant explosion? Does this mean his **Fire arrow** is more powerful?

[image: mahoraga-adapting-sukuna's-slashes]

Comment: Supposedly yes. Please note that by the same technique, he defeated Jogo who was pyrokinetic specialist. Quoting from [here](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Sukuna) "Fire (炎ほのお, Honō?)[10]: Sukuna can create and manipulate flames for long-range attacks by forming an arrow. These abilities exceed Jogo's, an unregistered special-grade curse whose defining trait involves extremely destructive pyrokinetic powers."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as of the date this answer is being written, we still do not have any explanations about Sukuna's "fire"/pyrokinetic powers. Sukuna has demonstrated this ability twice in the story, during his fight against Jougo and against Mahoraga.

There could be a couple of different reasons.

- Mahoraga was still recovering and adapting to the "Dismantle"(s) launched at it within Sukuna's domain. Sukuna managed to finish off the Shikigami before it could fully adapt. He even comments that he could launch a "Cleave" at Mahoraga, but if Mahoraga's adaptation works for all slashing attacks in general, then it might cause him problems. This compelled Sukuna to use his pyrokinetic abilities. So, the Fire Arrow may not be necessarily stronger; the technique hit Mahoraga while it was still recovering.
- The pyrokinesis exhibited by Sukuna could be an "inherited" Cursed Technique exclusive to him. Quite similar to Gojo's "Limitless". This could make it potentially stronger than his regular "Cleave" and "Dismantle" as Sukuna might have had more training and experience using his pyrokinesis and prefers to use it only for tormenting his opponents or as a last resort.
- The pyrokinetic abilities of Sukuna may be related to some sort of Binding Vow, which makes the technique extremely powerful (possibly more than Sukuna's Domain Expansion) but can only be used after a specified "cooldown" period.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with Sukuna's slashing attacks within the Malevolent Shrine Domain Expansion, Mahoraga might have been able to adapt because the attacks were primarily physical in nature, involving cutting or slashing. Mahoraga, being a skilled combatant, likely could adjust his strategy and defenses to counter such attacks, even if they were relentless.